# Can we download 8gb of file in one go on IOS device

Tags: ios, swift, mobile

I want to download a zip file which is 8gb. Is this possible in IOS or I will need to break that file in parts

Comment: Worth reading: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url_loading_system/downloading_files_from_websites including the linked articles

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can download files of any size as long as the user device has enough free space available. Just make sure to download it to disk instead of memory otherwise it might crash your app. You can use URLSession downloadTask method to download the file asynchronously.